# How to regist an Eureka client to a Eureka server cluster with loadbalance?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

When I deploy microservice eureka client and set eureka server's url like below:

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://10.118.28.94:7701/eureka/,http://10.154.32.88:7701/eureka/
```

I found the client always register into the first Eureka server(10.118.28.94:7701), and I want to know how to make loadbalance to prevent all the clients register into a same eureka server?  Should I adjust the order of the server list manually?

Comment: Usually, those eureka's should be clustered and share all registrations.

Comment: @spencergibb  I know, But if the clients set the same server url order, all the heartbeat and fetch service list requset will send to the first server, I want to know whether need make loadbalance to make clients register into difference servrer to share the press. I am not clear of the mechanism. Thx.

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-eureka-client-server-communication and https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-Eureka-Peer-to-Peer-Communication?

Netflix has an eureka server in each AWS zone and clients use that one first. So I guess the answer is yes, if you have cluster of 3 eureka servers, clients should pick one of them so writes are balanced.

Comment: @spencergibb Yes, I had read these. The thing I want to know is the way to make client "pick one of them" balanced. I worked base on spring cloud  and non-AWS environments.

Answer (score 2):

this may confuse you, please follow one step at a time

and [follow this link to understand micro services registration with eureka server](http://blog.abhijitsarkar.org/technical/netflix-eureka/)

or **start here**

to make eureka clustering, you need to run **two instances** of eureka server

configure eureka server **application.proerties** as follow

```
#EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION (ServerProperties)
server.port=8081

#Configuration for service registration with Eureka Server
eureka.instance.hostname=peer1
eureka.server.hostname=peer2
eureka.server.port=8082
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${eureka.server.hostname}:${eureka.server.port}/eureka/
eureka.server.renewalPercentThreshold=0.49

#self registration Configuration
eureka.client.registerWithEureka: false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry: false
```

**run application outside IDE after packaged eureka server as jar**

***Note***
           update your hosts information before running applications
                 in windows `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` open hosts file paste these

```
    127.0.0.1  peer1 
    127.0.0.1  peer2
```

now you are ready to run eureka

```
instance 1 : java -jar eurekaserveryourartifact.jar
```

to run the second instance, you need to override certain properties in **application.proerties** by passing them as VM arguments when running application, as below

```
instance 2 : java -jar -Dserver.port=8082 -Deureka.instance.hostname=peer2 -Deureka.server.hostname=peer1 eureka.server.port=8081 eurekaserveryourartifact.jar
```

**---------------------- Eureka   clustering completed till here  ------------**

access eureka1 : `peer1:8081 or localhost:8081`

access eureka2 : `peer2:8082 or localhost:8082`

make sure 1st eureka shows replica as **peer2** and 2nd server shows replica as **peer1**

---

**Now Register your services with eureka**

register your **services(eureka client)** with **1st eureka server**, automatically those will register with 2nd eureka server also. and clients should have following configuration in **application.proerties** as follow.

```
    #reading values from pom.xml
    spring.application.name=@artifactId@
    #service registration with Eureka Server
    eureka.server.port=8081
    eureka.server.hostname=peer1       
  eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${eureka.server.hostname}:${eureka.server.port}/eureka/    eureka.instance.instanceId=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
```

to test load balancing its better to run **multiple instances** of service, by overriding server port, as below

service ins1: `java -jar  serviceartifact.jar`

and

service ins2: `java -jar -Dserver.port=8082 serviceartifact.jar`

Now you can see 2 instances of service registered with **eureka1** and **eureka2**

while accessing these services, if one instance of service goes down another instance
(**note :** both services are running on different ports) url will provided to consumer of service automatically by eureka server.

and we can also do **client side loadbalancing using ribbon**